# Initiating a VPN Connection Programatically on Linux via Java, or Shell Script

Tags: java, linux, vpn

I have a Java Program that needs to invoke a URL, that is reachable only after a VPN connection has been established (to a remote VPN host). The program runs on a Linux box.

Therefore, I need to be able to start/stop the VPN connection as-needed (essentially I do not need it 24 hours).

What is the best way for this:

1. Can i create a VPN Connection programatically in Java? Is it even possible?
2. Can i install VPN Client software on Linux Machine, and then via a shell script (which i will invoke via Java), start/stop the VPN Client Connection whenever needed. Is this viable or better solution?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can initiate VPN connection from a program (it does not matter which programming language) by running appropriate administration command. The exact administration command is distribution or even installation specific.

Normally a VPN connection (provided by [OpenVPN](http://openvpn.net/)) will be started by (shell) command `/etc/init.d/openvpn start vpnname` or a wrapper script (RedHat-derivatives have one, other distributions may not). That command has to be executed as `root`, so you additionally need to prefix it with `sudo` and configure sudo so that the user running the application can run that command.

Since the command is specific to the installation, you'll need to make it configurable (and possibly ship default config appropriate for distributions you use).

There are other, mutually incompatible VPN implementations too. Each will have different command to start it, but each will have such command, so the implementation should be able to start any of them given appropriate configuration.

Note, that VPN generally may require password for starting. If it does, the password either has to be saved on the client, or you'll additionally need to provide means for user to enter it. How it would be passed is again VPN, distribution and possibly installation-specific.